# Trouble trying to use header C++

Tags: c++, class, header

I'm new to C++, and I'm trying to learn how to call a class from an external header .h file. I simply put the `testando.cpp`, `teste.h`, and `teste.cpp` in the same directory. That was the problem that appeared when I tried to compile the `testando.cpp`:

```
    /tmp/ccpF455q.o: In function `main'
testando.cpp:(.text+0x24): undefined reference to `teste::teste(int)'
testando.cpp:(.text+0x30): undefined reference to `teste::get()'
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status:
```

The code:

```
//teste.h
#ifndef TESTE_H
#define TESTE_H

class teste
{
private:
    int x;
public:
    teste(int p);
    int get();

};

#endif
```

---

```
//teste.cpp
#include "teste.h"

teste::teste(int p)
{
    x=p;
}

int teste::get()
{
    return x;
}
```

---

```
//testando.cpp
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
#include "teste.h"

int main()
{
    teste k(17);
    cout << k.get() << endl;
}
```

Do I need to compile the headers file, or do something else I didn't realize?

Comment: *How* are you compiling?

Comment: This should'nt really happen.. Your code seems fine. What and how are you compiling?

Comment: I'm compiling with the following command line:
g++ -o testando testando.cpp